# Wordpress capabilities and restricted categories access

Tags: hooks, user-roles

I've a Wordpress blog to share content with some people only. Users has to login to access this website.

I created new roles and new capabilities on this blog.

I've got some articles which belongs to a certain category that I would like to share only with people with a certain role.

Is there a hook I could use when somebody request an article, and where I could test if the curent user has the good capabilities, and so modify the request if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best hook should be `'template_redirect'`, when this hook is fired main query is already set, so you can look at queried object and if the user has no required capability you can redirect request *somewhere*:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
  if (
    (
      is_category( 'special-category' )
      || is_singular() && has_category( 'special-category', get_queried_object() )
    ) &&
    ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'special-cap' )
  ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
  }
} );
```